# Session cookie that expires

Tags: cookies, session-cookies

Is it possible to have a session cookie that expires? Ie. I want the cookie to last maximum 30 minutes, but also get deleted if the user closes his browser. Workarounds are also welcome.

Tried the `max-age` setting, but that made it not delete when the browser ends.

Comment: How about to use local storage to save cookies?　You could access data on local storage after original browser had closed.  Just an idea.

Comment: @Fumu7 that's a good idea, but it needs to be cookies, because a 3rd party integrates with that, and I wouldn't want them to change their implementation.

Comment: You can read and write cookies by Javascript. You can read and write contents of local storage. So save cookie to local storage when the specific page, and use that data to reproduce cookie when you need it.

Comment: Hmm, didn't think about that. Good idea, will take it into consideration if Robby Cornelissen's idea doesn't pan out.

Comment: Implement the expiration on the server side?  Have the value include a precomputed expiration when you set it; then every time you use the cookie on the server side, parse it and check the current time (seconds since the epoch) is greater than the cookie's preset time-to-die?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, you can't do both in one cookie. It's one or the other, so either:

- set the `max-age` to 30 minutes to create a persistent cookie; or
- don't set the `max-age` to create a session cookie.

What you could do, however, is create both a session cookie and a 30 minute persistent cookie with different names, and then base your session handling on the presence of both cookies.